# Heroku JPA without Spring No persistence provider Exception

Tags: java, jpa, heroku

Hi i have a Java web application developed in Eclipse, i follow the tutorials for deploying it on Heroku with Webapp Runner plugin but for some reason when i try to load the page (by enter the url on a browser) the page crash because it throws an `ExceptionInitializerError - Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default`. I searched in every stackoverflow post and all that i found and can't get to a solution, because there's no much info on deploying an app without Spring too.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
2017-07-07T11:17:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ...
2017-07-07T11:17:25.294561+00:00 app[api]: Release v58 created by user ...
2017-07-07T11:17:25.294561+00:00 app[api]: Deploy d8b63878 by user ...
2017-07-07T11:17:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-07-07T11:17:30.911310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 12449 target/*.war`
2017-07-07T11:17:32.605979+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-07-07T11:17:32.608981+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-07-07T11:17:33.084080+00:00 app[web.1]: Expanding MissingDog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war into /app/target/tomcat.12449/webapps/expanded
2017-07-07T11:17:33.084141+00:00 app[web.1]: Adding Context  for /app/target/tomcat.12449/webapps/expanded
2017-07-07T11:17:33.348108+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
2017-07-07T11:17:33.348119+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-12449"]
2017-07-07T11:17:33.371914+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:33 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
2017-07-07T11:17:33.371917+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017-07-07T11:17:33.375237+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
2017-07-07T11:17:33.375240+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting service Tomcat
2017-07-07T11:17:33.376247+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
2017-07-07T11:17:33.376248+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-07-07T11:17:33.566688+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
2017-07-07T11:17:33.566691+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: No global web.xml found
2017-07-07T11:17:34.549303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-07-07T11:17:35.364701+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:35 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
2017-07-07T11:17:35.364725+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491248+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491252+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.controllers.MissingDogListener
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491257+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491258+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.missingdog.util.JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory(JPAUtil.java:19)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491260+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.controllers.MissingDogListener.contextInitialized(MissingDogListener.java:46)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491262+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491263+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491264+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491265+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491265+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491266+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491267+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491267+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491268+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491269+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491270+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491270+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.missingdog.util.JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory(JPAUtil.java:17)
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491271+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 10 more
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491272+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491711+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
2017-07-07T11:17:35.491712+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2017-07-07T11:17:35.507783+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
2017-07-07T11:17:35.507786+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2017-07-07T11:17:35.508704+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Context [] failed in [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] lifecycle. Allowing Tomcat to shutdown.
2017-07-07T11:17:35.520378+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:35 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
2017-07-07T11:17:35.520385+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2017-07-07T11:17:35.527543+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
2017-07-07T11:17:35.527545+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-12449]
2017-07-07T11:17:35.533776+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 07, 2017 11:17:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
2017-07-07T11:17:35.533779+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-12449"]
2017-07-07T11:17:36.028977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-07-07T11:17:36.041958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-07-07T11:17:36.043441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Here my persistence.xml (which is in `Java Resources -> src -> META-INF -> persistence.xml`):

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://ec2-23-23-234-118.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d5rinm9divug9g"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="ildtjrmqyjqoam"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="5a121318dbe1dccaeb88b5cc1085f6c80745aa615fa69c49c19aef6b12469b2e"/> -->

            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my ServletContextListener:

```
package com.controllers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import com.missingdog.util.JPAUtil;

@WebListener
public class MissingDogListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public MissingDogListener() {

    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)  { 
        try {
            JPAUtil.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)  { 
        try {
            String databaseUrl = System.getenv("DATABASE_URL");
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(databaseUrl, ":@/");
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String dbVendor = st.nextToken(); //if DATABASE_URL is set
            String userName = st.nextToken();
            String password = st.nextToken();
            String host = st.nextToken();
            String port = st.nextToken();
            String databaseName = st.nextToken();
            String jdbcUrl = String.format("jdbc:postgresql://%s:%s/%s?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory", host, port, databaseName);
            Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", jdbcUrl);
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", userName);
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
            JPAUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory("default", properties); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If those are real username and password, you need to run `heroku pg:credentials:rotate` right now.

Comment: i don't understand the comment... the user and password rotates automatically... that's how i get them in runtime

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Postgres driver in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```